# I can not get this program to work I am missing something in the Java Swing

Tags: java, arrays, swing, class, jframe

Below is a list a copy of my code any help please. I am lost, I cannot get it to work and I am not getting an error therefore I do not specific question.  I began with other ways of writing this program. I need to enter a name and have it written to the form and rendered.

### Main

```
// Main Class//
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Contact Data Vault");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300,300));

    frame.setVisible(true);         
}

{
}
}
```

### Frame

```
//Frame Class
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
private JButton addButton, printButton;
private JLabel firstLabel, lastLabel;
private JTextField firstField, lastField;
private JPanel panel;
private JTextArea textArea;
private ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

public Frame() {
    super("MY APP");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(800,300));

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    firstLabel = new JLabel("First Name: ");
    lastLabel = new JLabel("Last Name: "); 

    firstField = new JTextField(10);
    lastField = new JTextField(10);

    addButton = new JButton("Add Person");
    addButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    printButton = new JButton("Display People");
    printButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    panel.add(firstLabel);
    panel.add(firstField);
    panel.add(lastLabel);
    panel.add(lastField);
    panel.add(addButton);
    panel.add(printButton);

    textArea = new JTextArea();

    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setVisible(true);
    }
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == printButton){
            for(Person p: people){
                textArea.append(p+"\n");
            }

            textArea.append("Display Button Pushed\n");
        }else if(e.getSource() == addButton){
                System.out.println("add button pressed");

                String firstName = firstField.getText();
                String lastName = lastField.getText();

                people.add(new Person(firstName, lastName));
                firstField.setText("");
                firstField.setText("");
        }
        }

        }
        }
```

### Person

```
       //Person Class
      public class Person {
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;

     public Person(String firstName, String lastName){
    this.firstName= firstName;
    this.lastName= lastName;
}

public String toString(){
    return lastName + ", " + firstName;
}
}
```

Comment: What does your debugging tell you?

Comment: It tells me nothing it just displays a blank window jframe. Some how it is not referencing the Frame Class. I have tried it several ways and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Contact Data Vault");
```

This will just be an empty frame.  It instead needs to be:

```
JFrame frame = new Frame();
```

(Then the next problems appear, but you need to ask a separate question about those.)

Comment: Thank you so much you have saved me.